# Active Directory users cannot launch java webstart apps

Tags: java, active-directory, java-web-start, icedtea

My problem is that i am trying to launch java web start application (.JNLP) on active directory users but the application wont launch. Icedtea-web only loads the app but then it just dosent launch and disappears.

I can launch the application normally on local users but not on the active directory users.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed. The problem was that opensuse didn't have write access to /tmp/ folder.